# Kafka Consumer один поток - один топик

Tags: java, многопоточность, apache-kafka

Есть много топиков сообщений из Kafka, например 20.

Нужно для каждого отдельного топика создать поток на чтение данных (Consumer).

Но должно быть не более 10 потоков одновременно, и далее по кругу.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил обычными средствами java через ConsumerThread